# Angular 4 function getting called that shouldn't on logout

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue when logging out. Let me say that the code is working but I'm getting an error in the console. Let me share my code to explain. I have a service to logout like so...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  email: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(private _afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

    register(email, password) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        userData => {
          resolve(userData);
        },
        error => {
          reject(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  login(email, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._afAuth.auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(userData => resolve(userData), error => reject(error));
    });
  }

  logout() {
    this._afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  getAuthUser() {
    return this._afAuth.authState.map(auth => auth);
  }
}
```

In my component, I'm utilizing the service like so...

```
submitLogout() {
  this._authService.logout();
  this._toastr.success('You successfully logged out!');
  localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  this._router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Notice that after I logged out the user, I'm changing the rote to `/login`.
The template that calls the `submitLogout()`...

```
<li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
    <a class="nav-link" (click)="submitLogout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a>
</li>
```

When I click the `Logout` link, the user indeed gets logged out. However, when the app changes route back to `/login`, I get the following error in the console...

[image]

Seems like a function gets called when changing the route. The `login-user.component.ts` contains a login function to login the user. The code for that file is like so...

```
ngOnInit() {}
```

Notice that I have nothing getting called when the file loads. The actual function that gets called is like so...

```
submitLogin() {
  this._authService
    .login(this.email, this.password)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Login: ', response);
      this._authService.getAuthUser().subscribe(auth => {
        console.log(auth.uid);
        let id = auth.uid;
        this._userService.getUserByAuthKey(id).subscribe(currentUser => {
          localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser[0].uid));
        });
        this._toastr.success(`Logged in successfully!`);
        this._router.navigate(['/']);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error Login: ', error.message);
      this._toastr.error(`${error.message}`, null, {
      dismiss: 'controlled',
      showCloseButton: true
      });
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
}
```

What I don't understand is why that function is getting called. At least looks like it. That function gets called only when a link in the navbar gets clicked. Do anyone know how I can get rid of this error. I have been debbugin without success for a day now.

Comment: You are getting error on 50th line of `login-user.component.ts`. what is that 50th line? Please check

Comment: `console.log(auth.uid)`. This function shouldn't get called though.

Comment: can you share the service code as well..looks like you are returning null from the service

Comment: I'm going to update the first snippet to show the entire `auth.service.ts`

Comment: Try  return this._afAuth.authState.map(auth => return auth);.....Well if it doesnt work,you might have to test the fireauth.As far as i know the error occures when you try access field of a null object.

Comment: Also change your function call to getAuthUser() :Observable<any>{}

Comment: You mean to change the definition of the function of `getAuthUser()` in the service to `getAuthUser() :Observable<any>{}`?

Comment: I did change the function in the `auth.service.ts` to the following... 

      `getAuthUser(): Observable<any> {
          return this._afAuth.authState.map(auth => auth);
      }`

and I still get the same error.